# BigQuery - can you add a value via ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to add a new column while loading data into BigQuery with a repeated / static value that isn't in my source file/data.

I have managed to add a nullable column to my table on load with the ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION option, but this just adds a column with null for values.

How would I go about setting a static value for each row in this new column?

My load config looks like this:

```
config= {
  'configuration'=> {
      'load'=> {
        'sourceUris'=> files_array,
        'schema'=> {
          'fields'=> fields_array
          },
        'schemaUpdateOptions' => [{ 'ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION'=> true}],  
        'destinationTable'=> {
          'projectId'=> my_project,
          'datasetId'=> 'my_dataset',
          'tableId'=> my_table
        },
        'sourceFormat' => 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
        'createDisposition' => 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
        'writeDisposition' => 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        'maxBadRecords'=> 10,
      }
    },
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do this in 2 steps:

Step 1: Load your data with the existing columns.

Step 2: `SELECT *, 3 AS new_column FROM ...`, and save the results of this query as a table.

Comment: Thanks, Felipe. I've been thinking, an alternative solution would work if I could append the filename when I load the data? I don't suppose that is possible? My filenames follow a convention that includes the ISO2 code.

Comment: Interesting question! Would you submit that as a different question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47325630/add-filename-as-column-on-import-to-bigquery @Felipe Hoffa