# Add filename as column on import to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

This is a question about importing data files from Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery.

I have a number of JSON files that follow a strict naming convention to include some key data not included in the JSON data itself.

For example:

```
xxx_US_20170101.json.gz
xxx_GB_20170101.json.gz
xxx_DE_20170101.json.gz
```

Which is `client_country_date.json.gz` At the moment, I have some convoluted processes in a Ruby app that reads the files, appends the additional data and then writes it back to a file that is then imported into a single daily table for the client in BigQuery.

I am wondering if it is possible to grab and parse the filename as part of the import to BigQuery? I could then drop the convoluted Ruby processes which occasionally fail on larger files.

Comment: Do you essentially do like a cross join on the client/file name to the table(s)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could define an external table pointing to your files:

[image]

Note that the table type is "external table", and that it points to multiple files with the `*` glob.

Now you can query for all data in these files, and query for the meta-column `_FILE_NAME`:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, _FILE_NAME filename
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can now save these results to a new native table.

[image]

Comment: This is great, thanks, Felipe. I'd just discovered this as you posted :)

Comment: question....does this work automatically if you add more files to the bucket folder?